# Karma test shows as 'passed' in IntelliJ, while there are still errors. (And CI/CD then fails)

Tags: angular, unit-testing, intellij-idea, karma-jasmine, teamcity

I'm working on an Angular project, trying to get all my tests to turn green.
They all showed green, but when I send it to CI/CD (Teamcity), it fails.
So I looked into the log of my own IDE (IntelliJ), and it turns out that some of the tests did report errors, even though they showed up as successful.

[image: Picture shows that all tests were successful even though there were errors]
The picture above shows that all tests were successful, even though there were errors

[image: My karma.conf file]
This is my karma.conf file.

Now, I'm not a unit test expert, but I'm trying to learn. So my question is: Is there a setting I've overlooked? Am I doing something wrong? How could I make my karma tests show that there's an error?
I would like karma to report those errors as a failed test, so that I can solve them more easily.

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a known issue unfortunately, please vote for [WEB-39326](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/WEB-39326/typescript-compilation-error-doesnt-fail-karma-test-rerun) to be notified on any progress with it